# Independent Poisson process properties

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

There are two types of incoming calls to a telephone office. The first type requires commercial information and the second type not. Suppose the arrival of these two types of calls can be represented by separate Poisson processes with rates $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}$. What is the probability that between two non-business calls come five business calls?

Comment: What's "chegem"? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I do not know where to start. I know that the time between two events is exponentially but do not know how to apply it when you have two independent processes.

Comment: @Did I see now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: each call is of type $1$ with probability $p = \lambda_1/(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$ and type $2$ with probability $q = 1-p$, and different calls are independent.  Geometric distribution...